# savon httperror 302 rails 3.2

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, soap, savon

I am using `savon 2.11.1` gem to get soap request and responses in my rails application. I am creating client Object using

```
Savon.client(wsdl: "sample_url", ssl_verify_mode: :none)
```

and invoking

```
client.call(:method_name, hash)
```

When I invoke call method I am getting this error from savon.

> HTTPError(302)

When I tried the URL from chrome soap client extension I am getting successful response.

Can anyone please help me on fixing this.

Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 3):

Finally I resolved the issue and thought of posting the answer as it might help someone.

We just need to use a global option "follow_redirects: true" in Savon client object. It works like a charm.

> The code is: Savon.client(wsdl: "sample_url", ssl_verify_mode: :none,
>   follow_redirects: true)

Thank you.